# Rakefile not calling default task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rakefile, simplecov

I am trying my hand at writing a rakefile, and have what I think should call simplecov and then call rspec to run tests, but when I run my rakefile nothing gets executed. Am I doing something wrong? Also, is there a way to give the `:spec` task a dependency, I want it to call `:simplecov` before it executes.

```
require 'rake'

task :coverage do
  require 'simplecov'
  SimpleCov.start 'rails'
end

require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)

task :default => [:coverage, :spec]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately default can only have one task but you're welcome to use a namespace to package tasks together.  Yours might look like:

```
require 'rake'

namespace :rspec_cov do
  task :coverage do
    require 'simplecov'
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  end

  task :spec do
    sh 'bundle exec rspec'
  end
end

task :testing => ["rspec_cov:coverage", "rspec_cov:spec"]
```

now running `rake testing` will run both those tasks as you wanted.  On a totally separate note, if you receive an exit code issue (like I did) there seems to be a bug in SimpleCov that they're working on ([issue here](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/281)).